# Converting byte[] to ArrayBuffer in Nashorn

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

How do I convert an array of bytes into `ArrayBuffer` in Nashorn? I am trying to insert binary data into a pure JavaScript environment (i.e., it doesn't have access to `Java.from` or `Java.to`) and so would like to create an instance out an array of bytes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like I was going about this the wrong way. It made more sense to convert it into `Uint8Array` since what I'm sending in *is* an array of bytes.

I created the following function:

```
function byteToUint8Array(byteArray) {
    var uint8Array = new Uint8Array(byteArray.length);
    for(var i = 0; i < uint8Array.length; i++) {
        uint8Array[i] = byteArray[i];
    }

    return uint8Array;
}
```

This will convert an array of bytes (so `byteArray` is actually of type `byte[]`) into a `Uint8Array`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're right about using a `Uint8Array`, but this code might be preferable:

```
function byteToUint8Array(byteArray) {
    var uint8Array = new Uint8Array(byteArray.length);
    uint8Array.set(Java.from(byteArray));
    return uint8Array;
}
```

Also, if you really need an `ArrayBuffer` you can use `uint8Array.buffer`.

Comment: I am not able to use `Java.from` unfortunately because I am in a pure JavaScript environment in Nashorn. But your answer is still helpful.

Comment: Java undefined, but uint8Array.buffer helped me a lot, thank you !