# How can I decode ASCII characters from strings?

Tags: javascript, character-encoding

I am parsing a binary file to extract the text content. This is for a library that can be run in either a Node environment or a web browser. I need to convert all characters to be the human-readable versions of the encoding. So I receive an example string like

```
'SeÃ±or and salvaciÃ³n and Number%3A 1234%3B %06%88'
```

and I expect the output to be

```
'Señor and salvación and Number: 1234; ♠'
```

Currently I am using a mixture of decoding and escaping strings using a function I found on another SO question. **I am absolutely OK with throwing it away in favor of something else that works better**. I know what I am doing is not ideal at all, but I am unsure of what I need to do to make this work correctly. The below example shows that function and the steps to get to final output which is close, but not perfect.

The other problem is that using `decodeURIComponent` will sometimes throw a `URIError: URI malformed` error depending on what kinds of input I give it

```js
function escapeString(str) {
  //A replacement for the deprecated escape method
  //https://stackoverflow.com/a/37303214/79677
  const allowed = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789@*_+-./,';
  str = str.toString();
  const len = str.length;
  let R = '';
  let k = 0;
  let S = '';
  let chr = '';
  let ord = 0;
  while (k < len) {
    chr = str[k];
    if (allowed.indexOf(chr) !== -1) {
      S = chr;
    } else {
      ord = str.charCodeAt(k);
      if (ord < 256) {
        S = '%' + ('00' + ord.toString(16)).toUpperCase().slice(-2);
      } else {
        S = '%u' + ('0000' + ord.toString(16)).toUpperCase().slice(-4);
      }
    }
    R += S;
    k++;
  }
  return R;
}

const str = 'SeÃ±or and salvaciÃ³n and Number%3A 1234%3B %06%88';
//Expecting: 'Señor and salvación and Number: 1234; ♠'

console.log(1, str);
console.log(2, escapeString(str))
console.log(3, decodeURIComponent(escapeString(str)));
console.log(4, unescape(decodeURIComponent(escapeString(str))));
```

How can I properly, correctly, and consistently decode/convert my strings to the human-readable versions?

Comment: [XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/306801)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You face a (mix of) [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*):

```
from urllib.parse import unquote
string = 'SeÃ±or and salvaciÃ³n and Number%3A 1234%3B';
unquote( string).encode( 'cp1252').decode( 'utf-8');
```

> ```
> 'Señor and salvación and Number: 1234;'
> ```

Rewritten to JavaScript (sorry for lame and dull-witted code):

```js
function byteToUint8Array(byteArray) {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/34821126/3439404
    var uint8Array = new Uint8Array(byteArray.length);
    for(var i = 0; i < uint8Array.length; i++) {
        uint8Array[i] = byteArray[i];
    }

    return uint8Array;
};
function getBytes(txt) {
    // 
    var bytes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; ++i) {
        bytes.push(txt.charCodeAt(i));
    }
    return byteToUint8Array(bytes);
};

var decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
const str = 'SeÃ±or and salvaciÃ³n and Number%3A 1234%3B' // %06%88';
//Expecting: 'Señor and salvación and Number: 1234;' // ♠'

console.log(1, str);
console.log(5, decoder.decode( getBytes( decodeURIComponent(str))));
```

**Note** that two trailing characters in your string (percent encoded as `%06%88`) are non-printable codes

```
- `␆` (U+0006,  *Acknowledge*)
- `` (U+0088,  *Character Tabulation Set*)
```

Comment: This looks to be much simpler, thank you!  I was unaware of `TextDecoder`, I will try this out later tonight.  I am aware those two characters are unprintable, but I still have to translate them to be actual characters somehow. Typically my parser/library avoids these because it know what sections to read text from, but there are some strange parts that are unavoidable and I just need something that will work without erroring out. This appears like it will work, thank you!

Comment: So in my library I am already receiving the characters as an `ArrayBuffer` at the point where I need to clean them up, I just simplified my question to exclude that.  Just using the `TextDecoder` is exactly what I needed! It replaced a ton of code and all my unit tests pass! You can see my implementation here: https://github.com/FiniteLooper/SongShowPlus-parser/blob/main/src/index.ts#L274-L287